# How to access "Toggle device toolbar" on chrome using Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

What I`v tried:

- Changing the user agent

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1')
driver = webdriver.Chrome( r"C:\Users\qwerty\PycharmProjects\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

- Sending keys

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome( r"C:\Users\qwerty\PycharmProjects\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.google.com')


driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.SHIFT + 'i')
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + Keys.SHIFT + 'm')
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: as I know currently Selenium has access only to HTML on page but not to other elements in browser. Maybe in older version it worked with older browser. You may need other tools like `PyAutoGUI` to send keys to system and it will send it to active window.

Comment: Its working, thanks for answering !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can s simulate the mobile emulation as shown below just by using chrome options. Try the below code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

mobile_emulation = {
    "deviceMetrics": { "width": 360, "height": 640, "pixelRatio": 3.0 },
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile Safari/535.19" }
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path/to/chromedriver.exe,chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://google.com")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I cant import Common_Methods.GenericMethods nor I can't install it with pip.
Anyway thanks for you answer

Comment: You can ignore that library, it was my local lib. Updated the answer.

Comment: If you feel the issue is resolved, please accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left handside in my answer. And feel free to up vote the answer.